# How to create a simple but fast container file for file storage with read/write capabilities

Tags: filesystems, file-management, storage, container

I'm trying to create single files to contain large amounts of files of arbitrary type, to facilitate storage and copying. One solution would be to put them in a zero compression archive. But I find that method to be very slow to read from, and even slower to write to.

I've found some hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257832/are-there-alternatives-for-creating-large-container-files-that-are-cross-platfor) that point to a solution by allocating a large file and creating some file system structure in it. I haven't been able to find any instructions on how to do that though, and moreover, how would one explore/read/write to such a file?

Are there any simple ways to achieve this that (preferably) don't deal with programming? Also, I saw the ISO format mentioned somewhere. Is it a faster alternative to regular archives?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking for. Why do you want this in a 'file' rather than a directory for example? You could use something like SQLite and store it in a file db but without more information it's impossible to decipher what you're trying to do.

Comment: Because single large files are much faster to copy, and are "neater" sitting on a hard-drive. Basically, I figure that for files that I don't frequently use, but occasionally access or update, I would like to store them separately. And when I need to copy them for backup or synchronization to other devices, it is much easier and faster. I have no clue if this is an uncommon use scenario, or if I just have no idea about the right terminology, and so couldn't find anything on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Disk Management]

Then

[image: Create and Attach]

Then Attach it

[image: Attach]

Then format it to whatever file system you want.  If you have a lot of small files use a small cluster size.

You can detach it when it is not in use, and upload the whole thing.
Then re-attach.

Depending on the file system you choose it may support native compression.  NTFS does.  No form of FAT 16/32/etc support compression.

Comment: I believe that's what I was looking for. It's worth noting that it can be mounted in a folder without assigning a drive letter. Can it be accessed directly by any program?

Comment: Any program **should** be able to access it.